# re-add CDATA when saving simpleXMLObject

Tags: php, xml, escaping, simplexml, cdata

Loading a rather large nested XML file via

```php
$content = simplexml_load_string(
    $xmlString, null, LIBXML_NOCDATA
);
```

Is there a simple way to add CDATA escaping back to **all nodes** when exporting/saving the xml back to a string?

I thought that something like this would work.

```php
 $xmlIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    new SimpleXMLIterator($xml_string), 
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
 );
 foreach ($xmlIterator as $nodeName => &$node) {
   $node->textContent = sprintf('<![CDATA[%s]]>', $node->textContent);
 }
```

as seen here https://stackoverflow.com/a/31983626/1468708

But then you couldn't use node via reference to update the node directly. Otherwise I would have tried to add cdata via the tree directly.

Comment: Just to be clear, are you adding *additional* CDATA nodes, or just putting back the ones you've stripped with `LIBXML_NOCDATA`? If the latter, the obvious answer is just to not use that option, since its only purpose is to strip them from the output. (It gets used a lot due to misunderstandings of debug output, but that's all it really does.)

Comment: well kind of putting back the stripped ones, they're stripped in the first place for easier syntax in an online editor, where the xml ist edited. 
before saving all nodes value need to be CDATA escaped again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SimpleXML tries to abstract away differences in *encoding* of the XML, and concentrate on the semantic data content, so it doesn't directly expose the difference between `<![CDATA[foo&bar]]>` and `foo&amp;bar`.

Luckily, PHP also has an implementation of the DOM, which does include these "lower-level" details - and you can use it interchangeably with SimpleXML using [dom_import_simplexml](https://php.net/dom_import_simplexml) and [simplexml_import_dom](https://php.net/simplexml_import_dom), which switch between the two APIs without re-parsing the XML.

Specifically, the DOM has "node types" of `XML_TEXT_NODE` and `XML_CDATA_SECTION_NODE`, with corresponding `DOMText` and `DOMCdataSection` classes. So you need to iterate the DOM recursively, finding any `XML_TEXT_NODE` nodes and replacing them with a new `DOMCdataSection` object with the same text.

We can use the recursive iterator you have already to get all the *elements* in the XML, and then switch to the DOM to handle their text content:

```
$simplexml = new SimpleXMLIterator($xml);

$xmlIterator = new RecursiveIteratorIterator(
    $simplexml,
    RecursiveIteratorIterator::SELF_FIRST
);
foreach ($xmlIterator as $nodeName => $node) {
    $nodeAsDom = dom_import_simplexml($node);
    var_dump($nodeAsDom); // DOM logic goes here
}
 
echo $simplexml->asXML();
```

For each DOM node, we then loop over its children looking for Text nodes and replacing them. Note that we need the new `DOMCdataSection` object to be "owned by" the same document as the original, so we use a helper function rather than directly calling the constructor:

```
    foreach ( $nodeAsDom->childNodes as $childNode ) {
        if ( $childNode->nodeType === XML_TEXT_NODE ) {
            $cdataNode = $nodeAsDom->ownerDocument->createCdataSection($childNode->data);
            $nodeAsDom->replaceChild($cdataNode, $childNode);
        }
    }
```

Comment: awesome! i did not know about the usage of`dom_import_simplexml()` 
much appreciated!